# Matlab : String vector - character subtraction

Tags: matlab, syntax, cryptography, octave, encryption

I'm trying to make a linear algebra-based algorithm for shift(Ceasar) cryptography cipher . Supposing I have a string : 'hello ' . When I'm trying to convert it into a (int)number matrix I do this :

```
'hello' - 'a'
```

And the result is

```
ans =

 7     4    11    11    14
```

This is the desired result . But if I subtract the character 'g' the result will be

```
ans =

 1    -2     5     5     8
```

I'd like to ask what happens in Matlab(or Octave) when I subtract a character and I get the results above .

Comment: If you have the [miscellaneous package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/miscellaneous/index.html) installed, it has the function `asci` which displays a nicely formatted table showing how each character is interpreted in decimal and hexadecimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mohit Jain wrote, the results you get are based on a conversion to [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) which is the most widely accepted way to numerically encode textual information. ASCII is also included as a subset in the current standard of [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), and on supporting platforms Matlab actually uses a 16-bit Unicode encoding, which enables it to not only represent the 95 printable characters of ASCII which support English text, but a large number of international scripts, special characters for applications in mathematics, typography and [many other fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). Explicit conversion between numeric and character data in Matlab is done through `char` and `double`:

```
>> double('aAΔ')
ans =
    97    65   916
```

A small latin letter 'a' has the ASCII code 97, a large latin letter 'A' the ASCII code 65, and a large greek letter Delta has the Unicode number 916. Since the latin letters are encoded in sequence with codes 97 to 122 for small letters and 65 to 90 for capitals, you can generate the English alphabet e.g. like this:

```
>> char(65 : 90)
ans =
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

When you apply an arithmetic operator like `-` to character strings, the characters are implicitly converted to numbers as if you had used `double`

```
>> double('hello')
ans =
   104   101   108   108   111
>> double('g')
ans =
   103
```

and therefore `'hello' - 'a'` is the same as

```
>> [104 101 108 108 111] - 103
ans =
     1    -2     5     5     8
```

Comment: That was very usefull and solved my question , thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It changes characters of string to their ascii value and then subtracts each value

```
'hello' - 'a' = 7 4 11 11 14 because h - a = 8 -1 =7
(these should be ascii values but i am using these values for simplicity because its all   relative)
 e-a=5-1=4 
 l-a = 12-1 =11 and so on
'hello' - 'g' 
 h-g=8-7=1
 e-g=5-7=-2 and so on
```